# How to lash a corner of a bamboo pergola?

Tags: knots, shelter, knot-identification

I'm considering building something akin to a bamboo pergola and tying it together with a rope. What would be the best method for tying its 'corners' where three poles meet?

From the [Wikipedia article on lashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lashing_(ropework)) and browsing other sources it appears that the likely choices for tying such 'corners' together are either to use square lashing twice or tripod lashing, but probably the first.

However, I came across images of bamboo scaffolds that to my untrained in lashing patterns eye seem to show a single binding at the 'corners'. Could that be the case?

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Sources of images:

- https://industrialhistoryhk.org/bamboo-scaffolding/
- https://www.flickr.com/photos/jocelyntam/6822942011

Answer (score 7):

To connect **two poles** (of roughly equivalent size) in a square angle you should be using the **square lashing**, as you already suggested.

Here is a good animated tutorial showing how to tie it:
https://www.animatedknots.com/square-lashing-knot

Note the steps no. 13-16 from the above tutorial, where you basically "circle" your lashing *between the two poles* on the plane of the two poles. This is the crucial step that makes the square lashing tight and will fix to the poles tightly.

To **fix three poles together** in right angles I suggest first fixing two of them using a square lashing, and then fixing the third one using another square lashing. This will also be a lot easier than trying something fancy while having to hold in place 3 separate poles to work the rope on.

Source: I learned this in the boy scouts, we have used this to build multi-story towers out of pine poles able to easily carry multiple people per story. When done correctly it is rock-solid.

Note that when used to bind bamboo poles or other poles with a low-friction surface I suggest you add a couple of extra windings to each step to make sure there is enough grip.

Comment: I'll second this solution -- tried and tested!